# How to apply /etc/environment variable changes to specific GUI application in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

Is there any way to apply changes in /etc/environment variable to specific GUI application like IntelliJ in Ubuntu without logout/restart of the system?

Answer (score 0):

/etc/environment is only used to set a default user environment, the values in it can be overridden. Just create a script that sets (with `export VAR=....`) the values of the relevant variables before calling your application:

```
export VAR=value
command "$@"    # All args to the script are passed verbatim to the command
```

For the simpler cases you can also use the one-liner syntax

```
VAR=value command arg1 arg2 ....
```

To execute the command with a specific value for VAR.

Comment: Could you provide some more details about the answer? How to make the new environment variable to reflect in IntelliJ in Ubuntu without logout/restart